# What are the limits of Facebook FQL queries and Multiqueries (Max number of multiqueries and rate limitations)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

Is there some documentation about limits of Facebook queries and multi-queries?I've found out by trying and testing that multi-queries start giving errors at around 250 multi-queries per request, but that is something which is not standard, because sometimes 249 multi queries work, sometimes don't.
Also, is there some rate limitation sistem for queries?

Comment: Have you gotten any information regarding this? I'm interested in knowing how many FQL queries / second that you can send. If there is any limit at all?

Comment: @PeterWarbo i ended up using 200 as a limiter and never had problems. Nothing official of course.

Comment: If I try to run a multi-querie with more than 15 queries the result set is empty

Answer (score 0):

[The Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) state that "If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day)." - meaning that as long as you don't cross the 100,000,000 API calls per day, you are OK.

You should check your multi queries for other reasons of limitation, like script time out or capacity limitations of your server. Post more details on what are you running so we could look.